# Sonata Admin - sonata_type_collection: select from the list of existing entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I'm trying to implement many-to-many relationship between `Page` and `Image` entity using `PageHasImage` bridge entity. In the `PageAdmin` I added the field like so:

```
->add(
      'galleryImages', 
      'sonata_type_collection', 
      array(
            'cascade_validation' => false,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'type_options' => array('delete' => false)
           ),
      array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position',
            'admin_code' => 'sonata.admin.page_has_image'
      )
 )
```

which gives me an option to add new `Image` field, and then either upload new image or select it from the list of uploaded ones. The upload part works as expected, but selecting from the already uploaded images list does nothing. The `Select` button in `Images` list has just '#' in its href and doesn't seem to do anything useful. There are also checkboxes next to listed images but no action buttons to make any use of the selection.

What should I configure to make the actions on the list mean anything?  My guess is there's something missing in the setters of relationsships or in lifecycle event methods but I'd apprecieate some guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I can see it's not a popular question but for any poor soul who comes across this issue soon - there there is a bug in Sonata. Also, I'd rate Sonata Admin documentation 4/10... I've spent a few days looking for a decent description of the various configuration parameters of sonata forms, being sure I have misconfigured something. Great way to spend your life, eh.

Here's the solution: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/issues/404

I'll copy it here for completeness' sake:

Commenting the following lines in Resources/views/CRUD/edit_orm_many_association_script.html.twig fixes the issue

```
if (this.nodeName == 'A' && (target.attr('href').length == 0 ||     target.attr('href')[0] == '#')) {
Admin.log('[{{ id }}|field_dialog_form_list_link] element is an anchor, skipping action', this);
return;
```

}

Comment: 2/10, we need to remind them the definition of API and how to write a documentation for it (or even generate it !!). And also how to store a version number using cookies or localstorage.. Or even sessionstorage !